# Can't access the stripe check-out page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I have written my server-side code by nodejs .
I have implemented a route to create a stripe checkout session, which contains a bunch of data about the object that is going to be purchased.

```
router.get(
  '/checkout-session/:productId',
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    //   1) Get the currently ordered product
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.productId);

    // 2) Create checkout session
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      expand: ['line_items'],
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      success_url: `https://nasim67reja.github.io/CareoCIty-ecommerce/`,
      cancel_url: `https://nasim67reja.github.io/CareoCIty-ecommerce/#/${product.categories}`,
      customer_email: req.user.email,
      client_reference_id: req.params.productId,
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            currency: 'usd',
            unit_amount: product.price * 100,
            product_data: {
              name: `${product.name} `,
              description: product.summary,
              images: [
                `https://e-commerceapi.up.railway.app/Products/${product.categories}/${product.images[0]}`,
              ],
            },
          },
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      mode: 'payment',
    });

    // 3) Create session as response
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      session,
    });
  })
);
```

Then on the front-end (ReactJs), I created a function to request the checkout session from the server once the user clicks the buy button.
So once I hit that endpoint that I created on the backend, that will make a session and send it back to the client. Then based on that session, the stripe will automatically create a checkout page for us. where the user can then input
here is my client side code:

```
const buyProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const session = await axios.get(
        `${URL}/api/v1/orders//checkout-session/${product}`
      );
      window.location.replace(session.data.session.url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error: `, error.response);
    }
  };
```

All was okay when I tried on the local server.But when I hosted my backend on the Railway, then I got an error[image]

I have also tried to put the stripe public & private key on the authorization header. but still got that error.I searched a lot but didn't find any solution. I will be very happy to get help from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your server on Railway doesn't have the correct secret key. It depends on how you initialize `stripe` in NodeJS, but normally if you read it from an environment variable, you want to make sure Railway also sets that value correctly.

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
```

Comment: I forgot to put the 'STRIPE_SECRET_KEY 'environment variable on the railway. That was a stupid mistake, and it wasted my whole day. Thanks a lot. You save me